# Where to set ElasticSearch request timeout?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I've looked everywhere including the documentation regarding where I can set the request timeout for elasticsearch without much luck.

In Visual Studio the intelliSense label for the property 'requestTimeout' states `Note you can set this to a high value here and specify a timeout on elasticsearch's side'

Can someone tell me where the setting is on the elastic side?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API Documentation under https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/request-timeout.html

Alternatively you can look at [Elasticsearch.Net and Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838067/elasticsearch-net-and-timeouts) for an example.

As far as i know, there is no request timeout parameter on the elasticsearch side.